# How to get data from this html tag

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I don't know how to assign the keyword that matches my topic.

```
console.log($container.handsontable('getCell', row, 0));
```

and I got

```
 <td class="htDimmed" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">*</td>
```

in return.

I want to get the data from a specific cell.
**How can you get data from a specific cell?**

Comment: what data you want for specific cell, please explain.

Comment: I don'y know hot to post image in comment. Here's the link. 
[link]http://postimg.org/image/63qpzzlyv/cc1692bb/

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one td with class `.htDimmed` then you could use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('htDimmed')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I've lot of htDimmed class. I use getCell to get specific column and it return me that val.

Comment: I suggest that you put id argument to td. Then you can get value of just it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do 2 things either you can give any class for specific cell or you can give id for that like below code.

```
 <td class="htDimmed spcell" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">*</td>
```

Here you can fetch data through this,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('spcell')[0].innerHTML;
```

or

```
<td class="htDimmed spcell" id="spid" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">*</td>
```

Here you can fetch data through id,

```
document.getElementById('spid').innerHTML;
```